# No animals vs. No people vs. No one

Tags: word-usage

With count nouns, **"no"** is more often followed by *plural* nouns to mean **"not any"** or **"zero"**. It is more idiomatic to say:

(1a) There are **no animals** in the field.
(2a) **No dogs** are allowed here.

than:

(1b) There is **no animal** in the field. (2b) **No dog** is allowed here.

................

If you visited a restaurant to see a friend and found no people there, you could say either one of these:

(3a) There are **no people** here. (3b) There is **no one** here.

Most agree that both are correct. Confusingly enough, however, many native English speakers say that in this example, (3b) is more idiomatic than (3a).

Why is (3b) more idiomatic?

Why does the preferred variant switch, when they are pretty much the same construction?

Comment: Interesting spot (though 'better sense' was not really a sound 'deduction'). And yes, 'There is / There's no one / nobody here' is much more idiomatic. I hesitate to say _That's just the way the language has developed_, but ....

Comment: Your examples (3) and (4) are not ungrammatical, they're just a little bit old fashioned. Example (6) is just a particular example of the same construction that hasn't happened to go out of fashion.

Comment: I was going to add an example with inanimate objects, and realised that with  'There are no tables in the room' and 'There is no table in the room', the preferred variant is context-driven. With a large room, say a bar, one would choose the former, while with a small room like a dining room, the latter would be more commonly used. With your (1) and (2), multiple animals might be expected (/multiple dog-owners trying to get you to make an exception!) But also with (3), multiple people rather than a loner might be expected. Hmm. It's probably the pull of the fossilised 'no one / nobody'.

Comment: Who says that? There are no people here and no one here are two ways  to say something. Everything depends on **context**. So, whoever is saying that is clueless. Sometimes, "more idiomatic" is overrated.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by idiomatic. Some expressions are common, others are uncommon and sound strange to native speakers. And “nobody” (which is probable even more common than “no one”) I know   would say “no person”, even the minority who talk about the prevalence of dogs. Perhaps you should try English Language Learners.